# Open Url from Swift 3.0

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, url

I'm building an app with Swift 3.0 and when the user click on the UIButton, I want to open a URL.

The URL is as like this : "192.169.1.19/RELE-3"

So, I'm building this code:

```
func sendHttpRequest(endPoint : String){
        let url = URL(string: endPoint)!
        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        request.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request.httpMethod = "GET"
        /*let parameters: [String: Any] = [
        "id": 13,
        "name": "Jack & Jill"
        ]*/
        //request.httpBody = parameters.percentEscaped().data(using: .utf8)

        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in guard let data = data,
            let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse,
            error == nil else {                                              // check for fundamental networking error
                print("error", error ?? "Unknown error")
                return
            }

            guard (200 ... 299) ~= response.statusCode else {                    // check for http errors
                print("statusCode should be 2xx, but is \(response.statusCode)")
                print("response = \(response)")
                return
            }

            let responseString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
            print("responseString = \(responseString)")
            }

        task.resume()
    }
```

If I try to start the application and call this function, I don't have any error but the page is not called.

Comment: may be there is a problem in the url...check it once

Comment: you need to enable NSAppTransportSecurity in info.plist to support not secure http connection.

Comment: You say "I want to open a URL" and "I don't have any error but the page is not called." What are you trying to do? Load a web page? If so, you are going about it completely wrong. The code you have written will read data from an HTTP website, but does nothing to display that data on a web page. To do that you either need to invoke the URL in Safari using one of the openURL commands, or you need to create a web view and tell it to open your URL.

Comment: Ok, guys, the problem is on the URL. I have fixed it and now I can call that URL, but I don't know why but the method sendHttpRequest is called at two times, and this is not good

Comment: But that would be a different question. You’ve trivially solved this question so please delete it.

Answer (score -1):

Might be ATS issue.
Open Plist as source code formate and add below Code.

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
        <key>192.169.1.19</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
            <false/>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
        </dict>
    </dict>
    <key>NSAllowsLocalNetworking</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

Adding Allow Arbitrary Loads with key value true will solve, but not recommended.